# Implement iOS password entry view in OS X Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, common-lisp

I need to create a view in OS X Cocoa that hides all but the last entered character (until that character is hidden after a set amount of time). Essentially I want to use a `UITextField` with `textfield.secureTextEntry = YES` in OS X Cocoa.

I couldn't find a way to import `UITextField` in OS X Cocoa. I don't think this is possible anyways, since `NSTextField` and `UITextField` are from two different frameworks.

`NSSecureTextField` in OS X Cocoa does not keep the last character visible for a set amount of time, and I could not find an instance or class property that I could set that would change this behavior.

I tried to roll my own implementation, starting from `NSTextField` and triggering events from `keyUp:`, but I'm running into problems with corner cases. My current approach is to change the text stored in `NSTextField` to hidden characters (all but last character, for a set amount of time, etc.). However with this technique, what happens when a user selects the 2nd thru 5th character in a 7-character password and deletes them. How can I then figure out which of the hidden characters were deleted, so that I can retrieve the correct entered password?

So I think if I need to roll my own implementation, I need to not change the actual text stored in the `NSTextField`, and instead alter the way that the view is displayed on the screen. However I can't find a way to do this currently. Help here would be appreciated.

I'll also say that I have a strong bias to not roll my own implementation. If anyone knows of a way that I can either leverage prior work or simply import `UITextField` to OS X Cocoa to solve this problem, I'd welcome (and strongly favor) those solutions.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm a bit split on this idea. The reason why UITextField behaves the way it does is because on-screen keyboards are harder to use than regular desktop keyboards (smaller key size, no tactile feedback etc). What purpose is there to reproduce this on OS X? (not bagging on your question, I'm just curious)

Comment: You can subclass `NSTextField` and provide a custom `drawRect:` but I think you might actually need to provide a custom `NSTextFieldCell` instead, and override its `drawRect:inView:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NSTextField`, I could not successfully separate the drawing of the text from the stored text. I tried customizing the `NSFormatter` and looking briefly into customizing the field editor. The closest I got was by customizing `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:`. This gave me control over drawing, but only when the field editor did not have control of the object (i.e., only when not editing text in the object). All approaches seemed overly complex for what I was trying to do.

Using `NSTextView` I was able to get this to work. The approach is to separate the drawing of the characters from the stored characters, and store the actual text in the object. The drawing method simply uses asterisks when necessary to hide the text, and that does not influence the text value stored in the object.

Here's some code that works using this approach. It's implemented in Clozure Common Lisp, communicating with Cocoa through Clozure's Objective C bridge:

```
(defclass easygui::cocoa-password-entry-text-view (easygui::cocoa-text-view)
  ((pending-fun :accessor pending-fun :initform nil)
   (visible-char-time-secs :reader visible-char-time-secs :initform 1))
  (:metaclass ns:+ns-object))

(defclass easygui::cocoa-password-entry-layout-manager (ns:ns-layout-manager)
  ((last-char-vis-p :accessor last-char-vis-p :initform nil))
  (:metaclass ns:+ns-object))

(defclass password-entry-text-view (text-view)
  ()
  (:default-initargs :specifically 'easygui::cocoa-password-entry-text-view))

(objc:defmethod #/initWithFrame: ((self easygui::cocoa-password-entry-text-view) (frame #>NSRect))
  (unwind-protect (call-next-method frame)
    (#/replaceLayoutManager: (#/textContainer self)
     (#/init (#/alloc easygui::cocoa-password-entry-layout-manager)))
    (#/setFont: self
     (convert-font "Courier" 12))))

(objc:defmethod (#/drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint: :void) ((self easygui::cocoa-password-entry-layout-manager) (glyph-range #>NSRange) (at-point #>NSPoint))
  (let ((glyph-cnt (#/numberOfGlyphs self)))
    (let ((hide-until (if (last-char-vis-p self) (1- glyph-cnt) glyph-cnt)))
      (dotimes (i hide-until)
        (#/replaceGlyphAtIndex:withGlyph: self i 13))))
  (call-next-method glyph-range at-point))

(defmethod dialog-item-hidden-text ((view password-entry-text-view))
  (let ((text (dialog-item-text view)))
    (let ((layout-manager (#/layoutManager (cocoa-ref view))))
      (with-output-to-string (strm)
        (dotimes (i (1- (length text)))
          (format strm "*"))
        (format strm "~a" (if (last-char-vis-p layout-manager)
                            (char text (1- (length text)))
                            "*"))))))

(defmethod cursor-at-end-of-text-p ((cocoa-self easygui::cocoa-password-entry-text-view))
  (awhen (#/selectedRanges cocoa-self)
    (when (eq (#/count it) 1)
      (awhen (#/rangeValue (#/objectAtIndex: it 0))
        (let ((pos (ns:ns-range-location it)))
          (let ((length (ns:ns-range-length it)))
            (when (eq length 0)
              (when (eq pos (#/length (#/string cocoa-self)))
                t))))))))

(objc:defmethod (#/keyDown: :void) ((cocoa-self easygui::cocoa-password-entry-text-view) the-event)
  (call-next-method the-event)
  (labels ((get-keypress (the-event)
             (let* ((chars (#/characters the-event))
                    (str (objc:lisp-string-from-nsstring chars))
                    (char (char str 0)))
               char)))
    (handle-keypress-on-view
      (easygui::easygui-view-of cocoa-self)
      (get-keypress the-event))))

(defmethod handle-keypress-on-view ((view password-entry-text-view) keypress)
  (let ((cocoa-self (cocoa-ref view)))
    (cond ((or (eq keypress #\rubout)
               (not (cursor-at-end-of-text-p cocoa-self)))
           (setf (last-char-vis-p (#/layoutManager cocoa-self)) nil))
          (t
           (setf (last-char-vis-p (#/layoutManager cocoa-self)) t)
           (setf (pending-fun cocoa-self)
                 (alambda ()
                   (when (eq #'self (pending-fun cocoa-self))
                     (setf (last-char-vis-p (#/layoutManager cocoa-self)) nil)
                     (#/setNeedsDisplay: cocoa-self #$YES))))
           (schedule-for-event-process
             (pending-fun cocoa-self)
             (visible-char-time-secs cocoa-self))))))
```